# how break out of scope ruby variable ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, scope

I have used the following code to delete lines from a file:

```
File.open("#{$whitelist}-tmp", "w") do |outFile|
  File.foreach("#{$whitelist}") do |li|
    outFile.puts li unless li.chomp[/\A#{instanceId}\z/]
    @comm = outFile
  end
end
FileUtils.mv(@comm, $whitelist)
```

It works, but I'm thinking that it's not the right way to do it, as I had to create an extra variable '@comm' just to communicate the filename out from the loop. If I used 'outFile' as the first argument of FileUtils.mv directly I got an undefined variable error.

So, how should I have done this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, what is the purpose of the surrounding `"#{...}"` in `"#{$whitelist}"`?

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense, IMO. `outFile` and thus `@comm` is a `File` object. What's more, after the block, it will be a `close`d file object. `FileUtils::mv` takes `String`s as arguments, not `File`s. I'm surprised it even works at all, I'd expect a `TypeError` being `raise`d.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: it does raise: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to assign a variable containing the filename before the block where you use it:

```
tempFile = "#{$whitelist}-tmp"
File.open(tempFile, "w") do |outFile|
  File.foreach("#{$whitelist}") do |li|
    outFile.puts li unless li.chomp[/\A#{instanceId}\z/
  end
end
FileUtils.mv(tempFile, $whitelist)
```

Comment: As @Jordan commented above, you can simply use `$whitelist` without the surrounding quotes and string interpolation in the second `File`. You also really shouldn't be using `$global` variables, like, ever.

Comment: Global variables are fine for smaller utility scripts

Answer (score 2):

Doc on [File.open](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open)

> If the optional code block is given, it will be passed the opened file as an argument and the File object will automatically be closed when the block terminates. **The value of the block will be returned from File.open.**

So we can do this

```
file = File.open("#{$whitelist}-tmp", "w") do |outFile|
  File.foreach("#{$whitelist}") do |li|
    outFile.puts li unless li.chomp[/\A#{instanceId}\z/]
  end

  outFile # return value of the block
end

FileUtils.mv(file, $whitelist)
```

#### Update

Am I missing something or this code just filters and rewrites the file? If so, it can be much simplified.

```
filename = $whitelist

content = File.readlines(filename)
filtered = content.grep(/\A#{instanceId}\Z/)
File.write(filename, filtered)
```

Comment: I'm not sure `mv` on a filehandle like this is even valid. I certainly wouldn't rely on it working in the future.

Comment: @JimStewart: yeah, docs/code don't hint at possibility of using handles at all. Anyhow, I offered an improved version :)

Comment: @JimStewart: checked, `.mv` on a handle doesn't work.

Comment: `%x|sed s/^#{instanceId}$//g #{$whitelist}|` :)

Comment: Eh? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed inline execution. Honestly, it could remove lines with shorter syntax, but I don’t remember it :)

Comment: @mudasobwa that was my lame attempt at admiration of your unix-fu. :) I myself am far less adept in that area.